# Passing by Reference in PHP 5.x

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, return-by-reference

I am studying for the Zend PHP5 Certification, everything looks good but i can not find real world examples for passing or returning variables my reference.

It would be very nice, if someone has an example when to use this?

Comment: This is PHP manual material: 1.: [Passing by Reference](http://php.net/language.references.pass) ; 2.: [Returning References](http://php.net/language.references.return)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to write a function that removes certain values from an array.

```
function remove_elements($array, $item1, $item2, ...) {
  ...
}
```

You could copy the array and return it. But what if you want to know if anything was removed? Instead you modify the array *in-place* and return the number of elements removed. So:

```
function remove_elements(&$array) {
  // remove elements
  return $number_removed;
}
```

If you create a complex structure inside your function you may want to return a reference to it rather than a copy of it. But this is a fairly marginal case because PHP uses copy-on-write (ie its not copied until it's modified) but there are some valid use cases.

Returning by reference makes more sense when you're writing a member function of a class. You could return a reference to a data member but this can also break encapsulation.

Lastly, it's worth noting that all objects are passed and returned by reference by default. Everything else is passed and returned by value.

Comment: Good answer for half the question, though this doesn't give info regarding returning by reference.

Comment: Still doesn't :P

function &foo():

Answer (score 1):

Pass by reference: functions like [asort()](http://php.net/asort)

```
$array = array(3, 2, 1);
asort($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects in php5 are passed by reference by default. (For a correct description see http://docs.php.net/language.oop5.references)

Passing arguments by reference has already been answered...

As a (real world) example for a return value by reference pick any [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) where a method returns a reference to the same object as its own call-context ($this). This wouldn't work (as expected) if the return value was a copy/clone.

E.g.

```
class MyClass {  
  protected $foo = 'n/a';
  protected $bar = 'n/a';

  function foo($val) {
    $this->foo = (int)$val;
    return $this;
  }

  function bar($val) {
    $this->bar = (int)$val;
    return $this;
  }

  function __toString() {
    return 'foo='.$this->foo.' bar='.$this->bar;
  }
}

$o = new MyClass;
$o->foo(1)
  ->bar(2);
echo $o;
```

This prints `foo=1 bar=2` and I think that's the result one would expect, no surprises here.
If the method returned $this by value, it wouldn't work anymore. You can test that by forcing php to return a copy. Instead of the `return $this` lines use

```
return clone $this;
```

and the output will be

```
foo=1 bar=n/a
```

(and I wouldn't call that interface intuitive ;-))

Comment: "Objects in php5 are passed by reference by default." This is wrong. "Objects" are not values and cannot be passed. `new MyClass` evaluates to an *object reference*. An object reference can be passed either by value or by reference, just like all other types. For all types of variables, a `&` parameter is passed by reference, otherwise by value. Above, there is no `&` in the parameter, so it is passed *by value*. An object reference can also be passed by reference, if so desired.

Comment: newacct: pedantic in this context but agreed, http://docs.php.net/language.oop5.references

Answer (score -1):

It could be useful, if you work with chainig,like:

```
    public function addObject(array &$someData){
$newObj = Fabric::create($someData);
$this->listOfObj[] = $newObj;
return $newObj;
}

....
$this->addObj(array('idontknow' => 'anything'))->setName('mr.knowitall')->save();
```

... Sry. Same as Volkers :( (The Fluent Interface is Chaining like i know it).

Image you have a fluent Interface with an load-method. The Load-interface replace or adds some data. Here it could be useful to act with an call by reference value $success to determine that the load was successful.

Return by reference:
Take some database-objects having a list of rows. The Nr. of rows points to right data of all objects (parallesl). If you return the nr. and pass it to the next object, you can skip the row in one object and skip in the others too. Always having a valide bunch of objects.

Comment: There is no pass by reference here. It is passing and returning by value.

Comment: Thanks. (addObject) Its returning by reference. Default sice it is an object. Its a good example, because you could change the returning object while changing the object in the list

Comment: no, you are working with an object reference (objects are not values in PHP 5), and you are returning it by value. Also, it is useless that you are passing `$someData` by reference, since you are not changing it.